# Creating several google maps marker based on address

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I am trying to place google map markers based on several address, i have manage to show them based on coordinates, but i dont have coordinates i only have address. Here is my code what i have for now

```html
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

```
var map;
        function initialize() {
          var styles = [{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"color":"#fcfcfc"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"color":"#fcfcfc"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"color":"#dddddd"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"color":"#dddddd"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"color":"#eeeeee"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"color":"#dddddd"}]}];

          var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
                                                        {name: "Styled Map"});


          // the position of the marker
          var zurichCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(47.3768866,8.541694);
          var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.4469659,8.5833443); 
          var latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(46.818188,8.227512); 




          var myOptions = {
            zoom: 11,
            center: zurichCenter,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
              mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
            }
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: latlng,
            icon: 'img/pin-default.png' // location of the pin image, depending of the skin used
          });

          var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: latlng1,
            icon: 'img/pin-default.png' // location of the pin image, depending of the skin used
          });       


          map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
          map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
          var center = map.getCenter();
          google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
          map.setCenter(center); 
        });
```

Comment: I haven'nt tried the geocoding api but curious did you try that coz in your question you are saying about coordinates and in Geocoding we can pass address text and this api will change it into lat and logi and search in map.

Comment: No i didnt tried, i know for that api, but how to pass this kind of the values?

Comment: I am not sure if I get your statement "this kind if values".But while looking at your code it looks like you have some coordinates and you are putting marker over there.if you can follow this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro and enter your street address you would get your address and once you get it you can put marker there,the way you are doing by putting the lat and longitude now.I am sorry if it was not at all helpful.

Comment: I need example what if i have address and not coordinates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?csw=1), as said in the comments, you can convert your address to coordinates.

You can find an example on how to use the API [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple).

I can't find an address in your code.

**EDIT:**

Here is a simple example (copied from the link above):

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = "Bergmannstraße 2, Berlin, Germany";

geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function (results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: resultsMap,
      position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
  }
  else {
    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' +    status);
 }
});
```

Working fiddles:

http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/1167/

http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/1164/

Comment: In the sample, there is code with custom adress ... see my edit in the post. change address to whatever you want

Comment: Yes but i have several adresses?

Comment: yo you just have to run the geocoder several times and add everytime the new marker.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/1164/
if you zoom out, you will see, that there are 2 markes.